# Does Open file descriptors on windows incur a performance cost

Tags: windows, winapi, visual-c++, file-descriptor

I am building a high performance application that streams data in from ~1000 different sources of on disk data (aka files) on demand on windows.

To minimize latency, I was looking into keeping all file descriptors open for the entire run time of the program. I was thinking of doing something like:

```cpp
#ifndef WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#endif

#include <windows.h>

#define MAX_NUM_HANDLES 1024

int main()
{
    //...

    HANDLE openHandles[MAX_NUM_HANDLES];
    unsigned long long fileSizes[MAX_NUM_HANDLES];
    for( int i = 0; i < MAX_NUM_HANDLES; ++i )
    {
        openHandles[i] = CreateFileA(filenames[i], GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED ,NULL);
        if( openHandles[i] != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE )
        {
            LARGE_INTEGER winFileSize;
            GetFileSizeEx(openHandles[i],&winFileSize);
            fileSizes[i] = (unsigned long long)winFileSize.QuadPart;
        }
        else
        {
            fileSizes[i] = 0;
        }
    }

    bool bRunning = true;
    while(bRunning)
    {
         //doing stuff with the handle
    }
    return 0;
}
```

but my question is does keeping open handles on windows incur a CPU performance penalty? I understand it consumes RAM space, but does it steal CPU time? Like does windows have background processes that scale in CPU runtime with extra open handles such that it would take processor time from me? Even if I measure it on my windows 11 machine I assume different versions of windows behave differently.

Any help or insights into the inner workings would be greatly appreciated, as I am trying to reduce processor impact as much as possible (I am configuring windows as well to reduce as many kernel processes as possible to give me more cpu time).

Comment: it must not take any cpu time. only memory

Comment: Hmm, handles themselves don't give you CPU penalty. But every time you call a Windows API with a handle, it will involve a kernel roundtrip including security checks etc. How large are those files? Are you sure they reside on a SSD? Because HDD with milliseconds of access time will not give you high performance at all. Can you cache the files?

Comment: @ThomasWeller files can range from 1MB to 1GB. Enough where i need to stream in data(aka calling read file when I need data from them) when it is needed. I can cache small files not not the big ones due to there being more file memory than all of ram on the machine. But if the open handles don't incur a CPU penalty that is good to hear